# Check enum case without parameters

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have an enum:

```
enum StoresSortType {
    case address, number, lastInspectionDate, distance(CLLocation)
}
```

I want to check only case without parameters, like that:

```
 let type = StoresSortType.address
 if lastSorting.type == type {
     //logic here
 }
```

But I have an error: `path_to_file.swift:197:69: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'StoresSortType' operands`

How I can do that with ignoring of `CLLocation` parameter in last case?

Comment: You need to make the `StoreSortType` confirm to `Equatable` protocol. http://nshipster.com/swift-comparison-protocols/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch statement

```
switch( lastSorting )
{
 case .distance:
 break
 default:
 break
}
```

Comment: And how I can compare it with `type`?